# The last three digits of $3\times7\times11\times15\times \cdots \times 2003$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How I can find the last three digits of $n$

$$n=3\times7\times11\times15\times \cdots  \times 2003?$$

Comment: Why so many upvotes for a question with no context or attempt?

Comment: $$\prod^{501}_{n=1}(4n-1)$$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318386/calculate-1-times-3-times-5-times-cdots-times-2013-last-three-digits

Comment: @Lost1 First of all, Why it need a context ? And are you sure that I've not tried ?

Comment: @Ewin: Help us help you.  If you provide the context and your efforts, Answers suited to your level of study are more likely (and expeditious).

Comment: For instance, whether you know Chinese Remainder Theorem is a context. When a problem can be solved in different ways, the "context" of a chapter in a book will help answerers point you to the right approach. Finally, if you show what you've tried, the context is that you've made a good will effort to solve the problem yourself - many of the best answerers here will not answer problems that look like homework if there is no effort on your part.

Comment: It's ok guys. I'll do that next time.

Answer (score 13):

Let $x=\prod_{n=0}^{500}(4n+3)$, then the answer is $x \mod 1000$.

By Chinese remainder theorem it is sufficient to calculate modulo $125$ and $8$.

But $125 $ is a divisor of $x$, so for modulo $125$  we have the congruence:

> $$x\equiv 0 \mod 125.$$

For modulo $8$  there are two cases : $4n-1 \equiv 3 \mod 8$ for $n$ even and $4n-3 \equiv -1 \mod 8$ for $n$ odd. The first case occurs $251$ times, the second occurs $250$ times. We use $3^2 = 9\equiv 1 \mod 8$ to calculate $x \mod 8$:

> $$x \equiv 3^{251}(-1)^{250} \equiv 3^{251} \equiv 3 \mod 8.$$

So we only need to check multiples of $125$ until they suffice the above congruence. The answer is

> $875$

Comment: I think it might be more clear if you stated "but 375 is a divisor of x , since it is 3 more than a multiple of 4...", otherwise the statement that 125 is a divisor of x may not be very obvious.

Comment: I was reading this question,i understood the steps but did not understand from where does $875$ come from and one more thing,i think $4n-1 \equiv 3$ mod $8$ for $n$ odd.@benh.Am i correct?

Answer (score 1):

def f(i)=3*(3+4)*.....(3+i*4) mod 1000.
One finds f(13)=125, f(14)=375, f(15)=625, f(16)=875.
Now f(17)=f(16)*(3+(16+1)*4)=f(16)*(64+7)=875*7=125 mod 1000.
Similarly f(18)=375, f(19)=625, f(20)=875.
Thus, beginning f(13), there is a period of 125, 375, 625, 875 and we have f(2003)=875.

Comment: Sorry, typo: Please read: "we have f(500)=875".

Comment: Learning LaTeX has never harmed anyone...Or maybe yes..